# Interpret several values as NULL when copying CSV file in PostgreSQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I want to copy a CSV file into the table `r`. In the file, the string `"NULL"` represents `NULL`, so I tried:

```
copy r from 'file.csv' WITH NULL AS 'NULL' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;
```

This works. But another file contains two values that represent NULL: The string `"NULL"` and an empty string `""`. How can I declare that **several values** should be interpreted as `NULL`?

Comment: technically "" isn't null its a blank string most of the time they are thought of the same but they can have different meanings.  You could always just run an update statement after importing to change the several values to NULL.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that, as the column is a timestamp and it only allows timestamps and NULL.

Comment: yeah you would have to import as VARCHAR then convert to timestamp after handling the invalid values.  Sorry I don't know postgressql's import method so I will let one of that platforms experts answer. cheers

Answer (score 1):

As @Matt alluded, the best option here is to import the column as `text` and then convert it to `timestamptz`. So create the table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE r (
    ...
    t timestamp with time zone,
    ...
);
```

Then import the data using `COPY` as you suggested. Finally convert the timestamps like this:

```
ALTER TABLE r
ALTER COLUMN t
TYPE timestamptz
USING
    CASE t
        WHEN 'NULL' THEN NULL
        WHEN '' THEN NULL
        ELSE t::timestamptz
    END;
```